# Why I cannot access form angular's properites in JS such as $error?

Tags: angularjs

I cannot access angular's Form members. I don't have a clue why. I'm using angular 1.4. The full code is at: http://jsbin.com/lujojiduru/edit?html,js,console,output

```
angular.module('test',[]).controller('testController', function($scope){
   $scope.sendInvitations = function(){
   var error = myForm.NewInvitations.$error;
   console.log('sent');  
   console.log('value: ' + error );
   };
});
```

the value of $error is always undefined.  Any idea?

Comment: What's `NewInvitations`? And please include the form HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var error = myForm.NewInvitations.$error;`

should be:

`var error = $scope.myForm.NewInvitations.$error;`

Notice the `$scope`

This is assuming you have the `name="myForm"` on your `<form>` tag

So something like:

```
<div ng-controller="testController">
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
...
</form>
</div>
```

you can also, if you prefer, send in the validity of your form, to your method on the controller.

So:

`<button  class="btn btn-success" ng-click="sendInvitations(myForm.$valid)">Send Invitations</button>`

And in your controller:

```
$scope.sendInvitations = function(isValid){
   if(!isValid)
      return;
};
```

***Update***

You also don't have any errors.

Add `required` to your input.

So your controller is now:

```
angular.module('test',[]).controller('testController', function($scope){

  $scope.sendInvitations = function(){
    debugger;//
    var error = $scope.myForm.NewInvitations.$error; 
    console.log('sent');  
    console.log(error );
  };
});
```

and your input

```
<input style="width: 95%" name="NewInvitations" type="email" ng-model="newInvitations" required />
```

This is an update to your bin

http://jsbin.com/hebikucanu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I just tried $scope.myForm.NewInvitations.$error; in JsBin and is undefined also.

Comment: because you don't have any errors. - just adding some to my answer

Comment: you also want to add `novalidate` to your form tag. This prevents the browser from validating the form and showing it's messages rather than what you want to show, and how you want to show it.

Answer (score 1):

`myForm` is not accessible in the global scope.  You can pass it in as an argument to `sendInvitations`.

```
ng-click="sendInvitations(myForm)

$scope.sendInvitations = function(myForm){
```

It's unlikely that you'd need to do this, though.  You can do use the `myForm` properties in the view.

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you should never *touch* the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Meaning, you should never invoke HTML elements directly as you would in traditional HTML/JS settings. ([read more](http://blog.freeside.co/2013/09/12/decoupling-from-the-dom-with-angular/))

Angular encourages the use of ng-model to employ `two-way binding` as a means to communicate between the controller and the view. ([angular two-way data binding tutorial](http://www.angularjstutorial.com/tag/ng-model/))

Thus, the first change you should attempt is to replace

```
var error = myForm.NewInvitations.$error;
```

with:

```
var error = $scope.NewInvitations;
```

This will cause the code to run.

But it appears that you want to retrieve the email input validation error and display it through angular.

**[Here is an excellent explanation with a tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D) that I think achieves what you're trying to do.** If you just want to see the code in action, [try this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/bKBcVMMvUlDqBbXeC9OC). (Be sure to hit the `Run` button.)

Hope this helps!